# Is it true that $\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{n-k}k$ outputs the $(n+1)$th Fibonacci number, where $m=\frac{n-1}2$ for odd $n$ and $m=\frac n2$ for even $n$?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, summation, binomial-coefficients, fibonacci-numbers

> Does $$\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{n-k}k=F_{n+1}$$ where $m=\left\{\begin{matrix}
> \frac{n-1}{2}, \text{for odd} \,n\\ 
> \frac n2, \text{for even} \,n
> \end{matrix}\right.$ hold for all positive integers $n$?

***Attempt***:
I have not yet found a counterexample, so I will attempt to prove it.
$$\text{LHS} =\binom n0 + \binom{n-1}1+\binom{n-2}2+...+\left\{\begin{matrix}
\binom{1+(n-1)/2}{(n-1)/2}, \text{for odd} \,n\\ 
\binom{n/2}{n/2}, \text{for even} \,n
\end{matrix}\right.$$
Now using the identity that $\binom nk + \binom n{k+1}=\binom {n+1}{k+1}$, where $k$ is a positive integer, I find that $$\binom{n-1}1=\binom n1 - 1, \\ \binom {n-2}2=\binom n2-2\binom n1+3,\\ \binom {n-3}{3} =\binom n3 - 3\binom n2 + 6 \binom n1 - 10, \\ ...$$ This pattern suggests that the coefficients of $\binom{n-4}4$ will be square numbers, those of $\binom{n-5}5$ will be pentagonal numbers, etc. However, I cannot see a way to link these results to any Fibonacci identity.

***Edit***: @Jack D'Aurizio♢ has provided a very succinct proof to this, but is there a more algebraic method to show the equality?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proof of the Hockey-Stick Identity: $\sum\limits_{t=0}^n \binom tk = \binom{n+1}{k+1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1490794/proof-of-the-hockey-stick-identity-sum-limits-t-0n-binom-tk-binomn1)

Comment: @GuyFsone: the point here is not to prove the hockey stick (or stars and bars) identity, but to understand how it is related to Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I got it thanks

Comment: See [The Fibonacci numbers occur in the sums of "shallow" diagonals in Pascal's triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Use_in_mathematics).

Comment: There is also a very simple proof: [by induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/61627).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculating $\sum_{0\le k\le n/2} \binom{n-k}{k}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61615/calculating-sum-0-le-k-le-n-2-binomn-kk)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a simple combinatorial interpretation. Let $S_n$ be the set of strings over the alphabet $\Sigma=\{0,1\}$ with length $n$ and no occurrence of the substring $11$. Let $L_n=|S_n|$. We clearly have $L_1=2$ and $L_2=3$, and $L_n=F_{n+2}$ is straightforward to prove by induction, since every element of $S_n$, for $n\geq 3$, is either $0\text{(element of }S_{n-1})$ or $10\text{(element of }S_{n-2})$, so $L_{n+2}=L_{n+1}+L_n$.

On the other hand, we may consider the elements of $S_n$ with exactly $k$ characters $1$.
There are as many elements with such structure as ways of writing $n+2-k$ as the  sum of $k+1$ positive natural numbers. Here it is an example for $n=8$ and $k=3$:

$$ 00101001\mapsto \color{grey}{0}00101001\color{grey}{0}\mapsto \color{red}{000}1\color{red}{0}1\color{red}{00}1\color{red}{0}\mapsto3+1+2+1.$$
By [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) it follows that:
$$ L_n = F_{n+2} = \sum_{k=0}^{n}[x^{n+2-k}]\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)^{k+1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n+1-k}{k} $$
and by reindexing we get $F_{n+1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n-k}{k}$ as wanted.

Comment: I don't really get the interpretation of $S_n$. Say we have the string $0101$. What does that mean?

Comment: @TheSimpliFire: $0101$ it is an element of $S_4$, associated with $k=2$ and $2+1+1$.

Comment: $S_4$ has $8$ elements, namely $$0000,0001,0010,0100,0101,1000,1001,1010$$ associated with $$ 6, 4+1,3+2,2+3,2+1+1,1+4,1+2+1,1+1+2.$$

Comment: Thank you. But why is $0010$ associated with $3+2$?

Comment: @TheSimpliFire: add an initial and a final zero to get $000100\mapsto 3+2$.

Answer (score 3):

Here is more of an algebraic solution through generating functions. We have

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\binom{n-k}{k}x^n
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}\binom{n}{k}x^{n+k+1}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^{2k+1}\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}\binom{n}{k}x^{n-k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^{2k+1}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+k}{k}x^{n}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^{2k+1}\frac{1}{(1-x)^{k+1}}\\
&=\frac{x}{1-x}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{x^2}{1-x}\right)^k\\
&=\frac{x}{1-x}\frac{1}{1-\frac{x^2}{1-x}}\\
&=\frac{x}{1-x-x^2}
\end{align}
where on the last line we arrived at the well known generating function for fibonacci numbers. So by equality of coefficients it follows
$$F_{n+1} = \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor (n)/2\rfloor}\binom{n-k}{k}.$$

Comment: clever use of summations and series!

Answer (score 1):

A while back, I have had done this proof combinatorically while solving a different probability question on [Quora](https://qr.ae/py8I8t).

**Suppose, you toss a fair coin $n$ times. What is the probability that no two consecutive heads appear?**

$\underline{\textbf{Notations}}\tag*{}$
For the sake of brevity, I'll denote:

- The set of favourable outcomes when a coin is tossed $n$ times (i.e., all the possible arrangements of length $n$ of the letters $H$ and $T$ such that the subsequence $HH$ doesn't occur in them) by $\zeta_n$.
- Cardinality of a set by enclosing it in a pair of pipes $|\cdot|$.
- Rounding to the nearest integer by a pair of square brackets $[\cdot]$.
- Integer part i.e., floor function by $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$.
- Golden ratio $(1+\sqrt 5)/2$ by $\phi$.
- A sequence $\{x_0, \ x_1, \ x_2, \ldots\}$ by $\{x_n\}$.
- Those elements of $\zeta_n$ which

  - end in $H$ by $H_n$.
  - end in $T$ by $T_n$.

---

$\underline{\textbf{Combinatorial Perspective}}\tag*{}$

- $\zeta_0=\{\emptyset\}$ because if the coin is not tossed, we still have a valid null arrangement. $|\zeta_0|=1\tag{1}$
- $\zeta_1=\{H, T\}$ and hence, $|\zeta_1|=2\tag{2}$
- $T_n$ and $H_n$ are disjoint and $\zeta_n=T_n\cup H_n$ which implies that: $|\zeta_n|=|T_n|+|H_n|\tag{3}$
- $T_n$ is generated by appending a $T$ to the elements of $\zeta_{n-1}$. Thus: $|T_n|=|\zeta_{n-1}|\tag{4}$
- $H_n$ is generated by appending an $H$ to the elements of $T_{n-1}$. Thus: $|H_n|=|T_{n-1}|=|\zeta_{n-2}|\tag{5}$ $\because$ $T_{n-1}$ is in turn generated by appending a $T$ to the elements of $\zeta_{n-2}$.
- From $(3)$, $(4)$ and $(5)$, $|\zeta_n|=|\zeta_{n-1}|+|\zeta_{n-2}|\tag{6}$
  From $(1)$, $(2)$ and $(6)$, we have a recurrence relation, $\displaystyle |\zeta_n|=\begin{cases} 1 & \text{if $n=0$}\\ 2 &\text{if $n=1$}\\ |\zeta_{n-1}|+|\zeta_{n-2}| & \text{if $n>1$}\end{cases}\tag*{}$
  This resembles the well-known Fibonacci sequence $\{F_n\}=\{0,1,1,2,3,\ldots\}$ but it is leading by two terms. $\boxed{|\zeta_n|=F_{n+2}}\tag*{}$

---

$\underline{\textbf{Alternate Perspective}}\tag*{}$
Let's generate $T_n$.

- Given any element of $T_n$, every $H$ necessarily occurs in an $HT$ pair. So we can generate $T_n$ by permuting the subsequences $HT$ and $T$.
- Say, there are $k$ number of $HT$ pairs and $(n-2k)$ number of free $T$s. (which indeed add up to length $n$ because every $HT$ pair is of length $2$.)
- There are $\displaystyle \frac{(k+n-2k)!}{k!\cdot(n-2k)!}=\binom{n-k}{k}\tag*{}$ unique permutations of them.
- $k$ i.e, the number of $HT$ pairs can be varied from $0$ to $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$.
- Thus we have: $\displaystyle |T_n|=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}\binom{n-k}{k}\tag*{}$
- From $(04)$, we have that $|T_n|=|\zeta_{n-1}|$. $\displaystyle\therefore |\zeta_{n-1}|=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}\binom{n-k}{k}\tag*{}$
  This is indeed a valid expression— just as valid as the previously discussed one according to which $|\zeta_n|=F_{n+2}$ i.e., on replacing $n$ by $n-1$, $|\zeta_{n-1}|=F_{n+1}$.
  Though this alternate perspective is of little use to the main problem, we just ended up revealing an interesting relation between the Fibonacci numbers and the *shallow diagonals* of Pascal's triangle: $\displaystyle \boxed{F_{n+1}=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}\binom{n-k}{k}}\tag*{}$

Answer (score 0):

This brings back some memories.

A while ago, my teacher had given the following question as an assignment:

> Let $a(n)$ denote the representation of $n$ as a sum of ones and twos. Find a closed form for $n$. (1+1+2 and 1+2+1) are different.

My teacher solved it using recurrence relation to show that $a(n) = F_{n+1}$, as $a(1) = 1, a(2) = 2$ and for $n >2$, $a(n) = a(n-1)+a(n-2)$ which can be seen when we go from $n-1$ to $n$ by concatenating a $1$, or go from $n-2$ to $n$ by concatenating a $2$.

I, however, completely missed the recurrence and finished with a sum which I didn't know how to simplify:
Let $k$ denote the number of twos in the sum. $k$ goes from $0$ till $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor$. Then we have $n-2k$ ones. We can assign the $k$ twos in $k+(n-2k)$ places in $\binom{n-k}{k}$ ways. This gives
$$a(n) = \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} \binom{n-k}{k}$$Thus,
$$\boxed{\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} \binom{n-k}{k} = F_{n+1}}$$

Comment: Moreover, my friend found $F_{n+1}$ using generating functions, almost the same method as Sil's answer