# The question is in how many ways you can express a natural number with sum of only 1 and 2

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, binomial-coefficients

How many ways you can express a natural number with sum of only $1$ and $2$. The ordering matter.
$3$ can be expressed in 3 ways: $$3=1+1+1=1+2=2+1$$I have found that it can be done by this way.(Nc0)*(1/0!)+((N)c1)*(1/N)+((N)c2)*(1/((N)*(N-1)))+...(Nck)*(1/N*(N-1)*(N-2)...(N-K+1)).where N is the maximum no of 1's to represent N as sum of . so that is N for sure. and k is the quotient you get by dividing n by 2. so i wanna ask that is there a simpler form to represent the sum

Comment: I do not understand your notations . Could you provide examples to explain them? On the other hand, could you use latex?

Comment: Please use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: i am new to latex

Comment: Please, don't yell.

Comment: The sum mentioned by the OP in their work is probably the same in the linked dupe. My answer in the linked dupe and an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/143434/1088689) explicitly address the OP's question.

Comment: ok i  can see there is the same answer posted.i didn't know that before. i am new to this site.  i thought i should ask help on this but didn't know there will this much comments and reply and i will be questioned as if i did duplicity. Whatever i will keep all this in my mind and take care next time.